# Gradle, extend/include default settings file in another

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration

Is it possible to extend default settings.gradle file?

For example, default settings file(**settings.gradle**) is as follows

`include 'Project1'
 include 'Project2'`

i want another settings file (**customsettings.gradle**) to include the content of settings.gradle and the below snippet to use in CI system.

```
setBuildFileName(rootProject)

def setBuildFileName(project) {
project.children.each { childProject ->     
childProject.buildFileName = "projectname.gradle"
assert childProject.projectDir.isDirectory()
assert childProject.buildFile.isFile()
setBuildFileName(childProject)
  }
}
```

I tried

```
include 'settings.gradle'

apply from: 'settings.gradle'`
```

but non of them worked.

Thanks

Comment: Why isn't this code in your top-level `build.gradle`?

Comment: i got the error "Could not find property 'children' on root project"

Comment: is it possible to extend settings files?

Comment: `apply from: 'settings.gradle'` (but not `include 'settings.gradle'`) should work as long as you execute the build with `-I customsettings.gradle`. I'm pretty sure the error is a result of using `include`.